# url_for and controller.controller_name not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, turbolinks

I was using controller.controller_name and url_for to highlight various items in a menu bar in my rails app. This worked locally, but once I pushed to Heroku, I was finding that the same menu item was always being highlighted no matter what page I was on, and it was because url_for and controller.controller_name never change even when I go to other views. Why might this be happening. Could this be related to turbolinks? I'm confused because I thought turbolinks was only related to my front end...?

Comment: Did you install `rails_12factor` gem for production group?

Comment: No I didn't - should I have?

Comment: Heroku docs strongly recommend to install that gem to avoid numerous problems with Rails apps deploying to Heroku. Can't say for sure if that gem will help you but it could.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and found out it was due to caching the rendered menu.